# Online video play issue in android

Tags: android

I am playing an online video. This video plays successfully on my android 4.0 devices but not played on android 2.2 and 2.3 devices. The video files are placed on my PHP server with mp4 format. The code is :

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("A video URL with mp4 format"), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```

If I copy this video on my devices's SDCard, then the same video gets played correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to the spaces in the file name of video so I have removed all the spaces from the mp4 file name then now it is played on android 2.2 and 2.3 also

Comment: if you got answer please close your question